# Vim - load view and mkview errors in command line window

Tags: vim, view, command, window

when I use this script in my .vimrc:

```
"Save and restore folds when a file is closed and re-opened
autocmd BufWinEnter                    ?* if(!empty(glob(expand("%:p")))) | silent loadview | endif
autocmd BufWritePost,BufLeave,WinLeave ?* if(!empty(glob(expand("%:p")))) | mkview          | endif
```

It creates errors when I open the command line window via `q:` (which opens up all the previous commands that I typed):

[image: error image]

How can I fix that, and make sure that this error does not occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain commands are not allowed in the [`command-line-window`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#command-line-window); [`:help E11`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#E11) explains that.

To deal with this in your `:autocmd`, there are several options:

- suppress any error by prepending `:silent!` to the `:mkview` command
- surrounding the call with `:try` ... `catch /^E11:/` to just selectively ignore this error, but report anything else
- add a check for the command-line window in your `:if` condition; in recent Vim versions, you can use [`getcmdwintype()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getcmdwintype%28%29); it returns an empty String in other windows; for a check that also works with older Vim versions, see [`ingo#compat#window#IsCmdlineWindow()`](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-ingo-library/blob/d835a9f3fb8552affc58f586eb54000b20cb5cdc/autoload/ingo/compat/window.vim#L13-L25) in my [ingo-library plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433)